# JavaScript, how to set up alert , that it will appear when countdown will end

Tags: javascript

What should I change or add that alert will appear when countdown ends on 0.
Now alert appears when countdown ends on 1.

```
    <script>
        function fn() {

        var seconds = document.getElementById("num").value;
        document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML=seconds;
      
        var countdown = setInterval(function() {
            seconds--;
            document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML=seconds;
            if (seconds <= 0) clearInterval(countdown);
            if (seconds == 0) alert("Time up!!");
        },1000);
       
        
        
        }
    

    </script>

    <p>Enter a number from 1 to 100: <br>
        <input id="num" type="text" name="number"></input>
    </p>

    <button type="button" onclick="fn()">Click me</button><br><br>

    <span id="test1"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually `alert` blocks all the event loop and UI. That's why other thing has to wait till `alert` is done with it's work.

You can use `setTimeout(() => alert('Times Up!'))` to solve your issue.

```html
    <script>
        function fn() {

        var seconds = document.getElementById("num").value;
        document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML=seconds;
      
        var countdown = setInterval(function() {
            seconds--;
            document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML=seconds;
            if (seconds <= 0) clearInterval(countdown);
            if (seconds == 0) setTimeout(() => alert('Times Up!'));
        },1000);
       
        
        
        }
    

    </script>

    <p>Enter a number from 1 to 100: <br>
        <input id="num" type="text" name="number"></input>
    </p>

    <button type="button" onclick="fn()">Click me</button><br><br>

    <span id="test1"></span>
```